# Headers disaligned when printing a table imported from a txt

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning Python.

I'm reading this `.txt` file:

```
user_id|age
1|20
2|25
3|30
4|35
```

with this script:

```
import pandas as pd
users = pd.read_table(r'provapd.txt', 
                      sep='|', index_col='user_id')
print(users.head(3))
```

it works, but the headers are not align in the output:

```
         age
user_id
1         20
2         25
3         30
```

Why?

Comment: Looks like the newline char after 'age' persists... does this also happen if you set the header keyword or specify the lineterminator?

Comment: @MrFuppes I tried with `lineterminator=\n` but nothing changes. With `index_col=0, header=[0,1]` the output is aligned but it seems a row of data is lost. Sorry but I am an absolute beginner :)

Comment: no worries, the behaviour is strange indeed. `pandas` should strip the newline char... do you use different `OS`, I mean e.g. Windows and Linux or MacOS? They use different lineendings so that might be a source of this behaviour. Otherwise, you could try to use `pandas.read_csv` instead and see if that is specific to `read_table` or maybe try to specify the enconding of the txt file.

Comment: @MrFuppes I'm on Windows 10, I created the txt by hand in Notepad++ with option Windows (CR LF) UTF-8. Nothing changes also if I use `pandas.read_csv`.

Comment: ok got on the wrong track here ;-) `user_id` is the index of your `df`. the index name is always 1 line below the column names if you display the `df`. add another column and you see what I mean.

Comment: @MrFuppes If you would like to add an answer I'll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `user_id` as the dataframe's index. `age` is a column name - if you display the dataframe in the console, column names will be displayed one line above the name of the index column(s).
If you e.g. add a column, you will see something like

```
         age  name
user_id           
1         20   tom
2         25  john
3         30   tim
```